# How to use sendmail on centos 6.4

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail

I am using `amazon Ec2` instance with `centos 6.4`. I tried this and i got error

```
echo "hello" | sendmail mymail@example.com 
sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
```

How can i fix that error

```
$ ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail
139512 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul  1 15:13 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta
$ man mta
No manual entry for mta
```

Comment: `/etc/alternatives/mta` is probably a symlink again. what does `readlink -f /usr/bin/sendmail` say?

Comment: @mata `/usr/bin/sendmail` this was the output

Comment: uuups, i ment `readlink -f /usr/sbin/sendmail`, forgot the s. that should show you what sendmail implementation is used.

Comment: @mata This thing solved my problem . can you tell me why it worked `sudo chkconfig --levels 235 sendmail on`

Comment: it enables the sendmail service to be started on runlevels 2, 3 and 5. that probably means that the service wasn't started before, which would explain the error message you got.